bitbucket pipeline - don't see test report
I am using bitbucket pipeline to run my pytest.  pytest generates the junit xml report, which according to bitbucket pipeline document, supports it.
however, I don't see report in either build or pull request. am I missing anything.
This is how my pipeline looks like.
    - step: &run_integration_test
        name: run_integration_test
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - cd tests/integration
          - pytest --junitxml=test-reports/report.xml
          - ls -ltr test-reports

Logs
time=2024-07-26T13:00:54Z level=error msg=1 error occurred:
    * [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/examples/env/dev/cloudstorage_func/.terragrunt-cache/5AlRCI-ti2VoYrikJkwV8Tsq2AA/n1gu-XxgcGeep8i9DccjWsXb8NE] exit status 1
- generated xml file: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/test-reports/report.xml

however, no report in pipeline build or pull request.



Try moving your test report XML files to a folder that's closer to the root folder of the Git clone. The documentation says that it will only scan for folders that are up to 3 levels deep. It's possible that the path /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/integration/test-reports/report.xml is too many levels deep. So try moving them higher up, like in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/test-reports/report.xml
You can do that with a command like this:
script:
  - cd $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR  # This should be something like /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
  - mkdir test-reports/
  - find . -maxdepth 5 -name '*test*.xml' -exec cp "{}" test-reports/  \;

Also note that the Bitbucket Pipelines dashboard will only display failed tests, and you should click on the "Tests" tab near the top.

If all your tests pass, there will be no output on the website. So you may want to use your own custom method in the YML file, to display a summary of the passed and failed tests.

that I able to see. I was talking about the different tab. what I realized is, the tab i was referring to only works for static analysis kind of report.
